# How to install folders from index to windows or linux?

Tags: linux, windows

I need to download some folders from this site

```
http://hspf.com
```

I can click on one folder and then download one file by clicking on it. but this is awful as I want to download all files. My question is how can I download this whole folder LangtangExample, for instance, to my pc.

I have both windows and linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to accomplish this:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://hspf.com/pub/HIMALA_BASINS/LangtangExample/
```